# CakePHP 3 - How do I block pages from non logged in users and redirect them to the login page?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How can I block several pages I've made (E.g. dashboard.ctp , crm.ctp) from users that are not logged in using the auth component and redirect them to the Login page if they try to access the above mentioned pages?

This is my AppController.

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
 {
    $this->Auth->allow(['display']);
 }

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'name',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ],
                 'scope' => [ 'status' => 1 ]
            ]
        ],
         'authorize' => ['Controller'], // Added this line
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
           'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'dashboard'
        ],
    ]);
}

 public function isAuthorized($user)
{
   // Admin can access every action

    if (isset($user['group_id']) && $user['group_id'] === 1) {
      return true;
        }
   // Default deny
     return false;
}
```

I'm using the cakephp version - 3.4.5.

Comment: If you're talking about the default pages controller, please clarify that and elaborate on what behavior exactly you are looking for (what should be allowed, and what shouldn't).

Comment: Yes i'm talking about the default pages controller. I want to restrict "non logged in users from accessing the above mentioned pages. 

@jbe answered my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you created dashboard.ctp, crm.ctp, in src/Templates/Pages and use the default PagesController. When you visit http://example.com/pages/crm CakePHP calls `PagesController->display()` and you allowed the display action for everyone:

```
$this->Auth->allow(['display']);
```

Remove it and decide in `isAuthorized()` if you want to allow it or not.